# How to attach (on an as needed basis) all packages imported by a package in R?

Tags: r, package

I'm creating new functions for a custom package, let's call it `customR`. In the `NAMESPACE` we import a number of other packages for use within `customR`. While developing new functions, I'd like a simple and robust way to load all the packages imported by `customR`.

I could, of course, simply use `library` to *manually* load each package `import`ed in `customR`'s `NAMESPACE`. However, there are a lot of packages (example below) and I'd prefer a more robust solution than simply copying the below from the `NAMESPACE` file and finding and replacing `import` with `library`:

```
import(data.table)
import(dplyr)
import(ensurer)
import(jsonlite)
import(lubridate)
import(magrittr)
import(mplyr)
import(reshape2)
import(scales)
import(stringr)
import(zoo)
importFrom(plyr,rename)
```

While I did not expect it to work, I tried `loadNamespace` and `requireNamespace` which did not show the imported packages when I used `search()`, so they did not appear to work.

To be clear, I do not want to `attach` these packages when loading `customR` in the normal course of things. Instead, while developing, I simply want to be able to quickly, simply, and robustly `attach`, on a ad hoc basis, all `import`ed packages used by `customR` when I am developing new functions for `customR`.

Comment: Are they in the "Imports" field of the "Description" file?  If so then it should work fine to load your customR package while you are developing it. I use the *devtools* package and RStudio for my development and it works great for this.  Just use `load_all()` when you want to work on the package.

Comment: Thanks @RichardScriven, yes they are in the `DESCRIPTION` file. I actually tried `devtools::load_all()`. Let me try it again, maybe I just missed that it loaded all the `import`ed packages.

Comment: @RichardScriven I tried it again, `devtools::load_all('path/to/customR')` does not load any of the packages under the `Imports:` section of `customR`'s `DESCRIPTION` file.

Comment: You're confusing loading with attaching. A namespace can be loaded without being attached to the search path. That's exactly what Imports does. `library` doesn't just load; it loads and attaches.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Thanks. Looking back at my question, I can see how it would look like I was confusing the functions / actions. I've edited the question to hopefully clarify my goal. I would like to `attach` all `Imported` packages on an *as needed basis* **not** as a default action when using `library(customR)` or `devtools::load_all(customR)`. Essentially, I'm looking for something like `attach_all_imported_packages(customR)`. Let me know if still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just make a new R file, eg. custom.R, that contains the above, and just load it when needed using. That way you just need to use library once in making the custom file. This way, should you update any of the packages, you just need to rerun source and it'll overwrite the previous libraries.

```
 source('custom.R')
```

Comment: I could but I was looking for a solution that would automatically adjust for any packages added / removed as `import`ed packages in `customR`.